# remove gitorious excessive usage restriction

Tags: gitorious

I've installed a new local [gitorious](https://gitorious.org/) server, however when I configure the users\projects\permissions I get:

```
Slow down!
Seems like you are just a tad busy, creating all those records that fast. Too much coffee?
To prevent abuse, we have denied your request due to excessive usage.
Feel free to contact us if you believe you have received this message in error.
```

That's great and all for later, but now I really need to configure a bunch of stuff. How can I remove this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

set:

```
disable_record_throttling: true
```

in `gitorious.yml`